# FxmlLoader Run Time Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

Im trying to make a simple program to store customers details, however when
I click the edit button Instead of the EditCustomerDialog.fxml showing I get a run time exception which I can not figure out.

Eclipse Mars.1 and built the fxml with JavaFX Scene Builder 8.0.0

Compiled with Java 8

Thanx in advance.

Main.java

```
package com.ed.gct;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.ed.gct.model.Customer;
import com.ed.gct.view.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;
 private ObservableList<Customer> customerData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 public Main(){
     customerData.add(new Customer("Andrew", "Eastwood"));
     customerData.add(new Customer("Samantha", "Eastwood"));
     customerData.add(new Customer("Joshua", "Eastwood"));
     customerData.add(new Customer("Lacey", "Eastwood"));
     customerData.add(new Customer("John", "Smith"));
     customerData.add(new Customer("Some", "Guy"));
 }

 public ObservableList<Customer> getCustomerData() {
        return customerData;
 }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Gold Coast Tanning");

    initRootLayout();
    showCustomerOverview();
}



private void initRootLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void showCustomerOverview() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/CustomerOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane customerOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(customerOverview);

        CustomerOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMain(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}





public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public boolean showCustomerEditDialog(Customer customer) {
    try {

          FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CustomerEditDialog.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)fxmlLoader.load();


        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Edit Customer");
        dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);


        CustomerEditController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller.setCustomer(customer);


        dialogStage.showAndWait();

        return controller.isOkClicked();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

CustomerEditController.java

```
package com.ed.gct.view;

import com.ed.gct.model.Customer;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

public class CustomerEditController {

@FXML
public Label firstNameEdit;
@FXML
public Label lastNameEdit;
@FXML
public Label addressEdit;
@FXML
public Label townEdit;
@FXML
public Label postcodeEdit;
@FXML
public Label dobEdit;
@FXML
public Label skinTypeEdit;
@FXML
public Label minsEdit;
@FXML
public TextArea medicalEdit;

private SimpleStringProperty firstName;
private StringProperty lastName;
private  StringProperty address;
private StringProperty town;
private StringProperty postcode;
private  StringProperty skinType;
private  StringProperty dob;
private IntegerProperty mins;
private  StringProperty medical;

private Stage dialogStage;
private Customer customer;
private boolean okClicked = false;
private IntegerStringConverter convert;



@FXML
private void initialize(){
    convert = new IntegerStringConverter();
}
    public void setDialogStage(Stage dialogStage){
        this.dialogStage = dialogStage;

}
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer){
        this.customer = customer;

        firstNameEdit.setText(customer.getFirstNameProperty().get());
        lastNameEdit.setText(customer.getLastNameProperty().get());
        addressEdit.setText(customer.getAddressProperty().get());
        townEdit.setText(customer.getTownProperty().get());
        postcodeEdit.setText(customer.getPostcodeProperty().get());
        dobEdit.setText(customer.getDobProperty().get());
        skinTypeEdit.setText(customer.getSkinTypeProperty().get());
        minsEdit.setText(convert.toString(customer.getMinsProperty().get()));
        medicalEdit.setText(customer.getMedicalProperty().get());

    }

    public boolean isOkClicked(){
        return okClicked;
    }

     @FXML
        private void handleOk() {
            if (isInputValid()) {
                firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstNameEdit.getText());
                lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastNameEdit.getText());
                address = new SimpleStringProperty(addressEdit.getText());
                town = new SimpleStringProperty(townEdit.getText());
                postcode = new SimpleStringProperty(postcodeEdit.getText());
                dob = new SimpleStringProperty(dobEdit.getText());
                skinType = new SimpleStringProperty(skinTypeEdit.getText());
                mins = new SimpleIntegerProperty(convert.fromString(minsEdit.getText()));
                medical = new SimpleStringProperty(medicalEdit.getText());
                customer.setFirstNameProperty(firstName);
                customer.setLastNameProperty(lastName);
                customer.setAddressProperty(address);
                customer.setTownProperty(town);
                customer.setPostcodeProperty(postcode);
                customer.setDobProperty(dob);
                customer.setSkinTypeProperty(skinType);
                customer.setMinsProperty(mins);
                customer.setMedicalproperty(medical);

                okClicked = true;
                dialogStage.close();
            }
        }

     @FXML
        private void handleCancel() {
            dialogStage.close();
     }

      private boolean isInputValid() {
            String errorMessage = "";

            if (firstNameEdit.getText() == null || firstNameEdit.getText().length() == 0) {
                errorMessage += "No valid first name!\n";
            }
            if (lastNameEdit.getText() == null || lastNameEdit.getText().length() == 0) {
                errorMessage += "No valid last name!\n";
            }
            if (townEdit.getText() == null || townEdit.getText().length() == 0) {
                errorMessage += "No valid town !\n";
            }

            if (postcodeEdit.getText() == null || postcodeEdit.getText().length() == 0) {
                errorMessage += "No valid postal code!\n";
            }

            if (dobEdit.getText() == null || dobEdit.getText().length() == 0) {
                errorMessage += "No valid date of birth!\n";
            }

            if (skinTypeEdit.getText() == null || skinTypeEdit.getText().length() == 0) {
                errorMessage += "No valid skin type!\n";
            }

            if (errorMessage.length() == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                // Show the error message.
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.initOwner(dialogStage);
                alert.setTitle("Invalid Fields");
                alert.setHeaderText("Please correct invalid fields");
                alert.setContentText(errorMessage);

                alert.showAndWait();

                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

CustomerOverviewController.java

```
    package com.ed.gct.view;

import java.util.Optional;

import com.ed.gct.Main;
import com.ed.gct.model.Customer;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

public class CustomerOverviewController {
     @FXML
    private TableView<Customer> customerTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customer, String> lastNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lastNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label addressLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label townLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label postcodeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label dobLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label skinTypeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label minsLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextArea medicalArea;
    String name;
    String lName;

    private Main main;
    private IntegerStringConverter convert;

    public CustomerOverviewController(){
        convert = new IntegerStringConverter();
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getFirstNameProperty());
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getLastNameProperty());



        showCustomerDetails(null);


        customerTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showCustomerDetails(newValue));
    }
    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;


        customerTable.setItems(main.getCustomerData());

}
            public void showCustomerDetails(Customer customer){
            if (customer != null){
            firstNameLabel.setText(customer.getFirstNameProperty().get());
            lastNameLabel.setText(customer.getLastNameProperty().get());
            addressLabel.setText(customer.getAddressProperty().get());
            townLabel.setText(customer.getTownProperty().get());
            postcodeLabel.setText(customer.getPostcodeProperty().get());
            skinTypeLabel.setText(customer.getSkinTypeProperty().get());
            dobLabel.setText(customer.getDobProperty().get());
            int mins = customer.getMinsProperty().get();
            String minsVal = convert.toString(mins);
            minsLabel.setText(minsVal);
            medicalArea.setText(customer.getMedicalProperty().get());
            name = customer.getFirstNameProperty().get();
            lName = customer.getLastNameProperty().get();
        }else{
            firstNameLabel.setText("");
            lastNameLabel.setText("");
            addressLabel.setText("");
            townLabel.setText("");
            postcodeLabel.setText("");
            skinTypeLabel.setText("");
            dobLabel.setText("");
            minsLabel.setText("");
            medicalArea.setText("No previous history");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleDeleteCustomer(){
        int selectedIndex = customerTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            Alert confirm = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            confirm.setTitle("Delete Customer...");
            confirm.setContentText("Are you sure you wish to delete "+ name + " " + lName);
            Optional<ButtonType> result = confirm.showAndWait();
            if ((result.isPresent()) && (result.get() == ButtonType.OK)){
                customerTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
            }

        } else {

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.initOwner(main.getPrimaryStage());
            alert.setTitle("No Selection");
            alert.setHeaderText("No Customer Selected");
            alert.setContentText("Please select a Customer in the table.");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleNewCustomer() {
        Customer tempCustomer = new Customer();
        boolean okClicked = main.showCustomerEditDialog(tempCustomer);
        if (okClicked) {
            main.getCustomerData().add(tempCustomer);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleEditCustomer() {
        Customer selectedCustomer = customerTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedCustomer != null) {
            boolean okClicked = main.showCustomerEditDialog(selectedCustomer);
            if (okClicked) {
                showCustomerDetails(selectedCustomer);
            }

        } else {

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.initOwner(main.getPrimaryStage());
            alert.setTitle("No Selection");
            alert.setHeaderText("No Customer Selected");
            alert.setContentText("Please select a customer in the table.");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerEditDialog.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="500.0"          xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"              fx:controller="com.ed.gct.view.CustomerEditController"> 
   <children>
  <GridPane layoutX="97.0" layoutY="176.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="70.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="241.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="380.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="380.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="73.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints maxHeight="90.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="98.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="147.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="139.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="139.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="37.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="150.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>
        <Label text="First Name">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Last Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Label text="D.O.B" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Address" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Town" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Post Code" GridPane.rowIndex="5">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Skin Type" GridPane.rowIndex="6">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Mins" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Medical" GridPane.rowIndex="8">
           <font>
              <Font size="14.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <TextField fx:id="firstNameEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
        <TextField fx:id="lastNameEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <TextField fx:id="dobEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <TextField fx:id="addressEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <TextField fx:id="townEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <TextField fx:id="postcodeEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <TextField fx:id="skinTypeEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <TextField fx:id="minsEdit" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <TextArea fx:id="medicalEdit" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
     </children>
  </GridPane>
  <ButtonBar layoutX="286.0" layoutY="446.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <buttons>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOk" text="OK" />
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCancel" text="Cancel" />
    </buttons>
  </ButtonBar>
  </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

new stack trace

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Sammy%20Poo%20xx/workspace/Gold%20Coast%202/Gold%20Coast%20Tannng/bin/com/ed/gct/view/CustomerEditDialog.fxml:74

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at com.ed.gct.Main.showCustomerEditDialog(Main.java:95)
at com.ed.gct.view.CustomerOverviewController.handleEditCustomer(CustomerOverviewController.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set     javafx.scene.control.Label field    com.ed.gct.view.CustomerEditController.firstNameEdit to     javafx.scene.control.TextField
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
 ... 71 more
```

Comment: Are you sure about the location `getClass().getResource("CustomerEditDialog.fxml")`??

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.` Make sure the location is being set correctly.

Comment: I think it should be `getClass().getResource("view/CustomerEditDialog.fxml")`

Comment: try `loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/ed/gct/view/RootLayout.fxml"));`

Comment: The error message indicates it cannot find the FXML file. It is expecting it to be in the package `com.ed.gct.view`, alongside the `CustomerOverviewController.class` (*note the class file, not the source code*). Check either your deployment directory or the jar file (depending on how you are running this) and see if it is there.

Comment: ok so i changed to your suggestion @MadushanPerera and now ive got a new error i will post the new trace

Answer (score 0):

> Can not set javafx.scene.control.Label field
>   com.ed.gct.view.CustomerEditController.firstNameEdit  to
>   javafx.scene.control.TextField

You are trying to use the TextField inside your FXML as a Label inside your CustomerEditController

So you have to change `firstNameLabel` type to `TextField`

```
@FXML
    private TextField firstNameLabel;
```

Comment: A project refresh and clean solved this issue ive just got to deal with a npe issue now. Im sure i will solve it soon enough... hopefully lol

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ed.gct.Main.showCustomerEditDialog(Main.java:108)
 at com.ed.gct.view.CustomerOverviewController.handleNewCustomer(CustomerOverviewController.java:128)                                                      controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);   and             boolean okClicked = main.showCustomerEditDialog(tempCustomer);